# not able to compile GTK program

Tags: c, linux, gtk

OS: Fedora 18
Kernel: 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64

I am not able to compile a simple GTK program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Command:

```
[root@localhost dir]##gcc -o graph graph.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
/lib64/libGL.so.1: undefined reference to _glapi_tls_Dispatch
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What does pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 command output shows ?

Comment: -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build against the library found with command pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0, so you need to execute the command to get the full library and include directory path, GCC will take the output (libs and cflags) as parameter, but GCC won't understand the command. So, you need to do the following -

```
           gcc -o graph graph.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

Edit based on question update:

On Fedora 18 - mesa-libglapi needs to be updated, to fix _glapi_tls_Dispatch undefined reference issue, with mesa-libglapi-9.0.1-1.fc18.x86_64 version this undefined reference problem remains. Updating the library fixes the issue -

```
          yum update mesa-libglapi
```

Comment: No, you missed the  "`" character in front and end of pkg-config command, which is used to execute a command in shell.

Comment: ohh sorry.. But the command still shows error.
Let me edit the question

Comment: hmm. so it must be some dependency issue.
Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: nm -D /usr/lib64/libGL.so | grep glapi - does this command shows _glapi_tls_Dispatch in output ?

Comment: mesa-libglapi-9.0.1-1.fc18.x86_64

Comment: I think this is the problem with Fedora 18 - here it's bugzilla link https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=969704, perhaps you need to update mesa-libglapi or it's related package, keep yourself upto date with the issue.